# google linechart view change

Tags: javascript, html, google-cloud-platform, charts, google-visualization

I have a one year data to show in the form of line chart , but the problem is initially its should show last one month statics only , then the user wants to view previous month data , then the user should scroll , i tried to do that , but its loading as a full one year data to chart,
is there any solution for this ,
thanks in advance

```
var data = [
  ["2023-01-01", 134],
  ["2023-01-02", 112],
   ....
//365 
]
const formattedData = data.map((row) => {
  return [new Date(row[0]), row[1]];
});

google.charts.load("current", { packages: ["corechart"] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  const dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  dataTable.addColumn("date", "Date");
  dataTable.addColumn("number", "Price");
  dataTable.addRows(formattedData);

  const options = {
    height: 800,
    explorer: {
      axis: "horizontal",
      keepInBounds: true,
      maxZoomIn: .1,
    },
    chartArea: {
      width: "60%",
    },
    hAxis: {  // current issue using this : it's showing only 30 days , not viewing previous month
      viewWindow: {
        min : formattedData[formattedData.length-30][0], 
        max: formattedData[formattedData.length-1][0],
      },
      format: "MMM dd",
    },
  };

  const chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(
    document.getElementById("chart_div")
  );
  console.log(
    new Date(formattedData[formattedData.length - 30][0]),
    new Date(formattedData[formattedData.length - 1][0])
  );
  chart.draw(dataTable, options);
}
```

without hAxis
[image: with out hAxis]

Comment: Under "Add a control" add a Data range control then click on it.  Set the default to "Last 30 Dyas"

Comment: sorry thought that was looker studio.  free from google: https://lookerstudio.google.com/u/0/navigation/reporting

Answer (score 0):

instead of pulling dates from the data table for the `viewWindow`...

```
    min : formattedData[formattedData.length-30][0], 
    max: formattedData[formattedData.length-1][0],
```

use a calculation to set the dates, (where `months` is previous or next)

```
// set view range
const dateBeg = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() + months, 1);
const dateEnd = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() + months + 1, 0);
options.hAxis.viewWindow = {
  min: dateBeg,
  max: dateEnd
};
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load("current", {
  packages: ["corechart"]
}).then(function () {
  const dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  dataTable.addColumn("date", "Date");
  dataTable.addColumn("number", "Price");
  dataTable.addRows(formattedData);

  const options = {
    height: 800,
    explorer: {
      axis: "horizontal",
      keepInBounds: true,
      maxZoomIn: .1,
    },
    chartArea: {
      width: "60%",
    },
    hAxis: {
      format: "MMM dd"
    }
  };

  const chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(
    document.getElementById("chart_div")
  );
  const monthsInput = document.getElementById('months');

  const btnPrev = document.getElementById('prev');
  const btnNext = document.getElementById('next');
  btnPrev.addEventListener('click', changeMonth);
  btnNext.addEventListener('click', changeMonth);
  changeMonth();

  function changeMonth(sender) {
    // init date range from data table
    const dateRange = dataTable.getColumnRange(0);
    const today = new Date();
    
    // set direction
    var dir = 0;
    if (sender) {
      dir = parseInt(sender.target.getAttribute('data-dir'));
    }
    
    // set number of months
    var months = parseInt(monthsInput.value);
    months += dir;
    monthsInput.value = months;
    
    // set view range
    const dateBeg = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() + months, 1);
    const dateEnd = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() + months + 1, 0);
    options.hAxis.viewWindow = {
      min: dateBeg,
      max: dateEnd
    };
    
    // prevent prev year
    if ((new Date(dateBeg.getFullYear(), dateBeg.getMonth() - 1, 1)).getTime() <= dateRange.min) {
      btnPrev.disabled = true;
    } else {
      btnPrev.disabled = false;
    }
    
    // prevent next year
    if ((new Date(dateEnd.getFullYear(), dateEnd.getMonth() + 1, 1)).getTime() >= dateRange.max) {
      btnNext.disabled = true;
    } else {
      btnNext.disabled = false;
    }
    
    // draw chart
    drawChart();
  }

  function drawChart() {
    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
  }
});

var data = [
  ["2023-01-01",134],
  ["2023-01-02",132],
  ["2023-01-03",135],
  ["2023-01-04",131],
  ["2023-01-05",136],
  ["2023-01-06",130],
  ["2023-01-07",137],
  ["2023-01-08",129],
  ["2023-01-09",138],
  ["2023-01-10",128],
  ["2023-01-11",139],
  ["2023-01-12",127],
  ["2023-01-13",140],
  ["2023-01-14",126],
  ["2023-01-15",141],
  ["2023-01-16",125],
  ["2023-01-17",142],
  ["2023-01-18",124],
  ["2023-01-19",143],
  ["2023-01-20",123],
  ["2023-01-21",144],
  ["2023-01-22",122],
  ["2023-01-23",145],
  ["2023-01-24",121],
  ["2023-01-25",146],
  ["2023-01-26",120],
  ["2023-01-27",147],
  ["2023-01-28",119],
  ["2023-01-29",148],
  ["2023-01-30",118],
  ["2023-01-31",149],
  ["2023-02-01",150],
  ["2023-02-02",148],
  ["2023-02-03",151],
  ["2023-02-04",147],
  ["2023-02-05",152],
  ["2023-02-06",146],
  ["2023-02-07",153],
  ["2023-02-08",145],
  ["2023-02-09",154],
  ["2023-02-10",144],
  ["2023-02-11",155],
  ["2023-02-12",143],
  ["2023-02-13",156],
  ["2023-02-14",142],
  ["2023-02-15",157],
  ["2023-02-16",141],
  ["2023-02-17",158],
  ["2023-02-18",140],
  ["2023-02-19",159],
  ["2023-02-20",139],
  ["2023-02-21",160],
  ["2023-02-22",138],
  ["2023-02-23",161],
  ["2023-02-24",137],
  ["2023-02-25",162],
  ["2023-02-26",136],
  ["2023-02-27",163],
  ["2023-02-28",135],
  ["2023-03-01",136],
  ["2023-03-02",134],
  ["2023-03-03",137],
  ["2023-03-04",133],
  ["2023-03-05",138],
  ["2023-03-06",132],
  ["2023-03-07",139],
  ["2023-03-08",131],
  ["2023-03-09",140],
  ["2023-03-10",130],
  ["2023-03-11",141],
  ["2023-03-12",129],
  ["2023-03-13",142],
  ["2023-03-14",128],
  ["2023-03-15",143],
  ["2023-03-16",127],
  ["2023-03-17",144],
  ["2023-03-18",126],
  ["2023-03-19",145],
  ["2023-03-20",125],
  ["2023-03-21",146],
  ["2023-03-22",124],
  ["2023-03-23",147],
  ["2023-03-24",123],
  ["2023-03-25",148],
  ["2023-03-26",122],
  ["2023-03-27",149],
  ["2023-03-28",121],
  ["2023-03-29",150],
  ["2023-03-30",120],
  ["2023-03-31",151],
  ["2023-04-01",152],
  ["2023-04-02",150],
  ["2023-04-03",153],
  ["2023-04-04",149],
  ["2023-04-05",154],
  ["2023-04-06",148],
  ["2023-04-07",155],
  ["2023-04-08",147],
  ["2023-04-09",156],
  ["2023-04-10",146],
  ["2023-04-11",157],
  ["2023-04-12",145],
  ["2023-04-13",158],
  ["2023-04-14",144],
  ["2023-04-15",159],
  ["2023-04-16",143],
  ["2023-04-17",160],
  ["2023-04-18",142],
  ["2023-04-19",161],
  ["2023-04-20",141],
  ["2023-04-21",162],
  ["2023-04-22",140],
  ["2023-04-23",163],
  ["2023-04-24",139],
  ["2023-04-25",164],
  ["2023-04-26",138],
  ["2023-04-27",165],
  ["2023-04-28",137],
  ["2023-04-29",166],
  ["2023-04-30",136],
  ["2023-05-01",137],
  ["2023-05-02",135],
  ["2023-05-03",138],
  ["2023-05-04",134],
  ["2023-05-05",139],
  ["2023-05-06",133],
  ["2023-05-07",140],
  ["2023-05-08",132],
  ["2023-05-09",141],
  ["2023-05-10",131],
  ["2023-05-11",142],
  ["2023-05-12",130],
  ["2023-05-13",143],
  ["2023-05-14",129],
  ["2023-05-15",144],
  ["2023-05-16",128],
  ["2023-05-17",145],
  ["2023-05-18",127],
  ["2023-05-19",146],
  ["2023-05-20",126],
  ["2023-05-21",147],
  ["2023-05-22",125],
  ["2023-05-23",148],
  ["2023-05-24",124],
  ["2023-05-25",149],
  ["2023-05-26",123],
  ["2023-05-27",150],
  ["2023-05-28",122],
  ["2023-05-29",151],
  ["2023-05-30",121],
  ["2023-05-31",152],
  ["2023-06-01",153],
  ["2023-06-02",151],
  ["2023-06-03",154],
  ["2023-06-04",150],
  ["2023-06-05",155],
  ["2023-06-06",149],
  ["2023-06-07",156],
  ["2023-06-08",148],
  ["2023-06-09",157],
  ["2023-06-10",147],
  ["2023-06-11",158],
  ["2023-06-12",146],
  ["2023-06-13",159],
  ["2023-06-14",145],
  ["2023-06-15",160],
  ["2023-06-16",144],
  ["2023-06-17",161],
  ["2023-06-18",143],
  ["2023-06-19",162],
  ["2023-06-20",142],
  ["2023-06-21",163],
  ["2023-06-22",141],
  ["2023-06-23",164],
  ["2023-06-24",140],
  ["2023-06-25",165],
  ["2023-06-26",139],
  ["2023-06-27",166],
  ["2023-06-28",138],
  ["2023-06-29",167],
  ["2023-06-30",137],
  ["2023-07-01",138],
  ["2023-07-02",136],
  ["2023-07-03",139],
  ["2023-07-04",135],
  ["2023-07-05",140],
  ["2023-07-06",134],
  ["2023-07-07",141],
  ["2023-07-08",133],
  ["2023-07-09",142],
  ["2023-07-10",132],
  ["2023-07-11",143],
  ["2023-07-12",131],
  ["2023-07-13",144],
  ["2023-07-14",130],
  ["2023-07-15",145],
  ["2023-07-16",129],
  ["2023-07-17",146],
  ["2023-07-18",128],
  ["2023-07-19",147],
  ["2023-07-20",127],
  ["2023-07-21",148],
  ["2023-07-22",126],
  ["2023-07-23",149],
  ["2023-07-24",125],
  ["2023-07-25",150],
  ["2023-07-26",124],
  ["2023-07-27",151],
  ["2023-07-28",123],
  ["2023-07-29",152],
  ["2023-07-30",122],
  ["2023-07-31",153],
  ["2023-08-01",154],
  ["2023-08-02",152],
  ["2023-08-03",155],
  ["2023-08-04",151],
  ["2023-08-05",156],
  ["2023-08-06",150],
  ["2023-08-07",157],
  ["2023-08-08",149],
  ["2023-08-09",158],
  ["2023-08-10",148],
  ["2023-08-11",159],
  ["2023-08-12",147],
  ["2023-08-13",160],
  ["2023-08-14",146],
  ["2023-08-15",161],
  ["2023-08-16",145],
  ["2023-08-17",162],
  ["2023-08-18",144],
  ["2023-08-19",163],
  ["2023-08-20",143],
  ["2023-08-21",164],
  ["2023-08-22",142],
  ["2023-08-23",165],
  ["2023-08-24",141],
  ["2023-08-25",166],
  ["2023-08-26",140],
  ["2023-08-27",167],
  ["2023-08-28",139],
  ["2023-08-29",168],
  ["2023-08-30",138],
  ["2023-08-31",169],
  ["2023-09-01",170],
  ["2023-09-02",168],
  ["2023-09-03",171],
  ["2023-09-04",167],
  ["2023-09-05",172],
  ["2023-09-06",166],
  ["2023-09-07",173],
  ["2023-09-08",165],
  ["2023-09-09",174],
  ["2023-09-10",164],
  ["2023-09-11",175],
  ["2023-09-12",163],
  ["2023-09-13",176],
  ["2023-09-14",162],
  ["2023-09-15",177],
  ["2023-09-16",161],
  ["2023-09-17",178],
  ["2023-09-18",160],
  ["2023-09-19",179],
  ["2023-09-20",159],
  ["2023-09-21",180],
  ["2023-09-22",158],
  ["2023-09-23",181],
  ["2023-09-24",157],
  ["2023-09-25",182],
  ["2023-09-26",156],
  ["2023-09-27",183],
  ["2023-09-28",155],
  ["2023-09-29",184],
  ["2023-09-30",154],
  ["2023-10-01",155],
  ["2023-10-02",153],
  ["2023-10-03",156],
  ["2023-10-04",152],
  ["2023-10-05",157],
  ["2023-10-06",151],
  ["2023-10-07",158],
  ["2023-10-08",150],
  ["2023-10-09",159],
  ["2023-10-10",149],
  ["2023-10-11",160],
  ["2023-10-12",148],
  ["2023-10-13",161],
  ["2023-10-14",147],
  ["2023-10-15",162],
  ["2023-10-16",146],
  ["2023-10-17",163],
  ["2023-10-18",145],
  ["2023-10-19",164],
  ["2023-10-20",144],
  ["2023-10-21",165],
  ["2023-10-22",143],
  ["2023-10-23",166],
  ["2023-10-24",142],
  ["2023-10-25",167],
  ["2023-10-26",141],
  ["2023-10-27",168],
  ["2023-10-28",140],
  ["2023-10-29",169],
  ["2023-10-30",139],
  ["2023-10-31",170],
  ["2023-11-01",171],
  ["2023-11-02",169],
  ["2023-11-03",172],
  ["2023-11-04",168],
  ["2023-11-05",173],
  ["2023-11-06",167],
  ["2023-11-07",174],
  ["2023-11-08",166],
  ["2023-11-09",175],
  ["2023-11-10",165],
  ["2023-11-11",176],
  ["2023-11-12",164],
  ["2023-11-13",177],
  ["2023-11-14",163],
  ["2023-11-15",178],
  ["2023-11-16",162],
  ["2023-11-17",179],
  ["2023-11-18",161],
  ["2023-11-19",180],
  ["2023-11-20",160],
  ["2023-11-21",181],
  ["2023-11-22",159],
  ["2023-11-23",182],
  ["2023-11-24",158],
  ["2023-11-25",183],
  ["2023-11-26",157],
  ["2023-11-27",184],
  ["2023-11-28",156],
  ["2023-11-29",185],
  ["2023-11-30",155],
  ["2023-12-01",156],
  ["2023-12-02",154],
  ["2023-12-03",157],
  ["2023-12-04",153],
  ["2023-12-05",158],
  ["2023-12-06",152],
  ["2023-12-07",159],
  ["2023-12-08",151],
  ["2023-12-09",160],
  ["2023-12-10",150],
  ["2023-12-11",161],
  ["2023-12-12",149],
  ["2023-12-13",162],
  ["2023-12-14",148],
  ["2023-12-15",163],
  ["2023-12-16",147],
  ["2023-12-17",164],
  ["2023-12-18",146],
  ["2023-12-19",165],
  ["2023-12-20",145],
  ["2023-12-21",166],
  ["2023-12-22",144],
  ["2023-12-23",167],
  ["2023-12-24",143],
  ["2023-12-25",168],
  ["2023-12-26",142],
  ["2023-12-27",169],
  ["2023-12-28",141],
  ["2023-12-29",170],
  ["2023-12-30",140],
  ["2023-12-31",171]
];

const formattedData = data.map((row) => {
  return [new Date(row[0]), row[1]];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<div>
  <!-- show previous month by default -->
  <input id="months" type="hidden" value="-1"/>
  <button id="prev" data-dir="-1">&lt;</button>
  <button id="next" data-dir="1">&gt;</button>
</div>

<div id="chart_div"></div>
```